# Getting the bounds of a NSString printed out with drawInRect

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring

I am currently drawing text on string, using drawInRect, restricted to a size using CGRectSize. It is also centred.

```
[text drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,nWidth,nHeight) withFont:font lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap alignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
```

What I need to find out is the size and offset of the actual drawn text.
Because it is centred, there is a very good chance that there is an X offset before text is drawn.

I've seen the command `boundingRectWithSize` but I think it may not be supported on IOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the size of the text,

```
CGSize size = [text sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGRectMake(0,0,nWidth,nHeight) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

(See [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html))

Then, since it is centered, the bounds will be

```
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake((nWidth - size.width)/2, ..., size.width, size.height);
```

Comment: Perfect, and sort of obvious once you said it!

Answer (score 0):

You want the method from the UIKit category on NSString...

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font
```

which gives you the size needed, and then you can compute your centering (or other) positions.